# Can I enter the Schengen area just before my visa expires?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, visa-extensions, visa-expiration

I'm Indian. Can I enter the Schengen area 5 days before my Czech visa expires? I have applied for extension, but I have not received a decision, so far.

Comment: If you travel before receiving your new visa, will you plan to remain in the Schengen area for only 5 days?

Comment: at present, I'm at my place and came for holidays and I would like to come back before my visa expires so that i can continue my work

Comment: So it's not a short-stay visa.  Is it a type D visa in your passport, or a separate residence permit card?  Do you have any receipt to show that you applied for an extension?  Did you receive any instructions about foreign travel when you applied for the extension?  If so, what did the instructions say?

Comment: yes, it is not short stay visa, it is long term researcher visa (residence permit card), they did not give me any receipt but I can ask them, i don't have any info regarding foreign travel.

Comment: Then I expect you should be okay.  I don't really know, though, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments on my question, I really appreciate it.